# How to concatenate several single results to one single with grouped result using rx?

Tags: rx-java2

It seems that should be a simple thing but I cannot find solution for that for a while. So I have a few Single sources which return different object and I want to get single with grouped result.

See example:

```
val singleA = Single.just(true) 
val singleB = Single.just(20) 
val singleC = Single.just("text")

val singleABC = Single.groupSingles(singleA,singleB,singleC)
singleABC.subscribe { resultA: Boolean, resultB:Int, resultC:String ->  //do something  }
```

in real all singles (A,B and C) performing long term operations and I don't want call them one-by-one but paraller.

similar to `Observable.combineLatest()` but with Single result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you're looking for is the [zip](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#zip-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.functions.Function3-) operator. `zip` can be used to associate emissions from multiple sources, and carries the distinction that it only emits when *each* of its underlying sources emits. so...

- if there are two sources, `zip` will emit two values when both sources emit.
- if there are three sources, `zip` will emit three values when all three sources emit.
- if there are four sources, `zip` will emit four values when all four sources emit.
- ...etc
- if any of the sources emits an error, `onError` will be triggered downstream

with that understanding, you can use the `zip` for your case like this:

```
val singleA = Single.just(true)
val singleB = Single.just(20)
val singleC = Single.just("text")

val singleABC =
    Single.zip(
        singleA,
        singleB,
        singleC,
        Function3 { resultA: Boolean, resultB: Int, resultC: String ->
          // do something
        }
    )
```

(looking back, you were actually quite close)

i found the [RxMarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#zip) page to be a useful resource in getting a hands-on, visual perspective on how different operators work. i'd encourage you to play around there for a bit to develop a feel for any you don't quite understand, as well as to discover some you didn't know existed. (it's not exhaustive in displaying all the operators, but it covers a lot of common ones).

Answer (score 0):

There is [`Single.zip()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#zip-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.SingleSource-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) operator - you can combine several `Single` sources into one.

If that operator does not satisfy your requirements, you can call [`Single.toObservable()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#toObservable--) for each `Single` source and use [`Observable.combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#combineLatest-io.reactivex.functions.Function-int-io.reactivex.ObservableSource...-)